# SQL Server : Group By not working

Tags: sql-server

I am building a query which works perfectly fine until I try to `GROUP BY tblWJC.WJCNo`

Query:

```
SELECT 
   tblWJCItem.AddedDescription
   ,tblWJC.WJCPrefix + Convert(Varchar(10),tblWJC.WJCNo) AS OurRef
   ,tblWJCItem.MaterialName
   ,tblStockFamily.StockFamily
   ,tblWJCItem.WeightToSend
   ,tblWJC.DateCreated
   ,tblWJC.WJCStatusID
   ,CASE 
       WHEN tblWJC.WJCStatusID < 2 THEN 'Pre Production'
       WHEN tblWJC.WJCStatusID < 4 THEN 'In Production'
       WHEN tblWJC.WJCStatusID > 4 THEN 'Ready To Ship'
       ELSE 'Awaiting Lab Results'
   END  AS [Status]
FROM 
   tblWJC 
INNER JOIN 
   tblWJCItem ON tblWJC.WJCID = tblWJCItem.WJCID 
INNER JOIN 
   tblStockFamily ON tblWJCItem.ProductFamilyID = tblStockFamily.StockFamilyID
INNER JOIN 
   tblCustomer ON tblWJC.CustomerID = tblCustomer.CustomerID
INNER JOIN 
   tblWJCStockStatus ON tblWJC.WJCStatusID = tblWJCStockStatus.WJCStockStatusID
WHERE 
   tblCustomer.CustomerName = 'ROLLS ROYCE' 
   AND tblWJCStockStatus.WJCStockStatus <> 'Stock Usage Confirmed'
GROUP BY 
   tblWJC.WJCNo
ORDER BY 
   tblStockFamily.StockFamily;
```

Can any one point out my mistake here? I am new to SQL Server, still learning by doing.

Thanks

Comment: What error message do you get?  What goes wrong when you try to group by that field?

Comment: Why are you trying to group by that column?   What results are you trying to get?

Comment: It doesn't give me a an error this query is going into the PHP code that i've developed which is fine the php error is stating my mssql query is failing and it cannot return any results.

Comment: Well, the error message should be clear enough, but you are selecting a bunch of columns and only grouping by one of them. You can't do that in SQL Server (or any other RDBMS other than MySQL) unless you put the rest of the columns on an aggregation function

Comment: @ Tab Alleman - trying to group by that as there are several lines that have the same WJCNo so want to group all the same WJCNo into one

Comment: why do you want group by non aggregate columns in select list should be present in group by

Comment: *so want to group all the same WJCNo into one* - What is your logic for doing this? If one `WJCNo`` has more than one different `MaterialName` associated for example, which one should you display? The same principal applies to all the different fields that are not unique.

Comment: You will need to use Row_Number() function to get a distinct line for tblWJC.WJCNo, GROUP BY wont help here.

Comment: I would recommend not putting your sql into your PHP. You would be better off using stored procedures to create some separation between PHP and SQL. It also forces you to parameterize your queries to help prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is common that you have a field aggregation error when you group a query by a field than you don't add an aggregate function on the fields that are part of your select statement. In your case, you're doing a group by the *tblWJC.WJCNo* column and then you are not aggregating your fields in the select statement.

```
SELECT tblWJCItem.AddedDescription
      ,tblWJC.WJCPrefix + Convert(Varchar(10),tblWJC.WJCNo) AS OurRef
      ,tblWJCItem.MaterialName
      ,tblStockFamily.StockFamily
      ,tblWJCItem.WeightToSend
      ,tblWJC.DateCreated
      ,tblWJC.WJCStatusID
      ,CASE WHEN tblWJC.WJCStatusID < 2 THEN 'Pre Production'
            WHEN tblWJC.WJCStatusID < 4 THEN 'In Production'
            WHEN tblWJC.WJCStatusID > 4 THEN 'Ready To Ship'
            ELSE 'Awaiting Lab Results'
            END  AS [Status]
```

If you group by a field and you want to put other fields in the select statement, these fields should be either aggregated or included in the group by statement and that seems logical since if you group data by a field, the other fields should aggregated by the group by field in order to display them.

Here is a link that contains all the aggregation function in SQL Server:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx

Comment: But isn't the question related to MS SQL server, not mysql?

Comment: Oh Sorry I will edit my answer, thinking about MS SQL Server and writing MySql